# opengl: How to do anti-aliasing for triangle

Tags: opengl, antialiasing

I'm learning OpenGL using Visual Studio C++. Just wondering how I go about doing anti-alias techniques for when I do glBegin(GL_Triangles)... it doesn't seem like a primitive type, or am I wrong?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Though its not specific what level of antialiasing you are expecting.
If you are using glut you can definitely try following code.

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
```

This will give you multi sampling anti aliasing. From what code you have given you are not doing anything in programmable mode or modern opengl so I think that should be sufficient to you as you dont have to do anything extra.

Comment: Ok then just include those calls and it should enable anti aliasing for you.